# Retrieving a String out of a runnable/TimerTask

Tags: java, android, timer, runnable

I have implemented a timer that parses a URL every 15min (the Timer task). 
An Object that i have created gets that data .I use it afterwards to display the data on the screen   .

Now , whenever i try to retrieve that Object/a String=Object.toString() out of the runnable I get null pointer exception and fatal errors .

My question is whether it is possible to do using some other technique to do it , or The Object cease to exist out of the runnable and there is not much we can do about it ;if that is the case can anybody tell me if there is another way of implementing a timer/runnable ?

Thanks a Lot

here is most of my code where i have a problem

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle)
           final  TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            TimerTask scanTask;
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Timer t = new Timer();                  
                scanTask = new TimerTask() {
                    public void run() {
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        URL url = null;
                                        try {
                                            url = new URL("http://www.eurosport.fr/");
                                        } catch (MalformedURLException e3) {

                                            e3.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                        /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
                                        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                                        SAXParser sp;
                                        try {
                                            sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                                        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e2) {

                                            e2.printStackTrace();
                                        } catch (SAXException e2) {

                                            e2.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                        /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
                                        XMLReader xr = null;
                                        try {
                                            sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                                            xr = sp.getXMLReader();
                                        } catch (SAXException e1) {

                                            e1.printStackTrace();
                                        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {

                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader*/
                                        ExampleHandler myExampleHandler = new ExampleHandler();
                                        try {
                                            sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                                        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e1.printStackTrace();
                                        } catch (SAXException e1) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e1.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

                                        /* Parse the xml-data from our URL. */
                                        try {
                                            xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                                        } catch (IOException e) {

                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        } catch (SAXException e) {

                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        /* Parsing has finished. */

                                        /* Our ExampleHandler now provides the parsed data to us. */
                                        ParsedExampleDataSet parsedExampleDataSet =
                                                                                        myExampleHandler.getParsedData();

                                       System.out.println(parsedExampleDataSet.toString());

                                        tv.setText(parsedExampleDataSet.toString());


                                     Context context = this.getBaseContext(); 

 // I also dont understand why inside the runnable getBaseContext() does not exist ???

    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.raw.nature1)
        context.setWallpaper(mBitmap);


                                    }


                           });

                    }  };
                    // I want to retrieve ParsedExampleDataSEt here in order to use it  is it Possible ????



                    this.setContentView(tv);



                   long temps=1*15*1000;

                t.scheduleAtFixedRate(scanTask, 300,temps );
```

Comment: Show some of your code and explain what you are using at the server side Servlets? or what? (Servlet itself is thread). If you mention these things it would be easy for people to answer :)

Comment: Use a service and a broadcast

Comment: I just added most of my code . I can get the data and display it on the screen . but i cant use it outside the runnable . If you feel that my code is not good enough feel free to edit and give me some feedback as i am new to android !

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Object out of a method(runnable) timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459245/get-object-out-of-a-methodrunnable-timer)

Answer (score 2):

The potentially ugly method:
Extend TimerTask and make an abstract method such as

```
public abstract void onUrlRetrivalFinished(String data);
```

When you create the TimerTask object you can now make a anonymous implementation of the method, and in that method handle the retrieved data.

The (in my opinion) less ugly method:

Make an interface such as:

```
public interface UrlRetrivalListener {
    public void onUrlRetrivalFinished(String data);
}
```

Sub-class TimerTask and make a field such as:

```
private UrlRetrivalListener listener;
```

Now make an implementation of the above mentioned listener interface, in which you handle the retrieved String. Pass the listener as a parameter to your TimerTask, or even let the TimerTask have more than one listener, and upon retrieving/parsing the data needed, you simply call the listeners onUrlRetrivalFinished() method.

This should do the trick, but some more information would be nice.

Comment: I just added most of my code . I can get the data and display it on the screen . but i cant use it outside the runnable . If you feel that my code is not good enough feel free to edit and give me some feedback as i am new to android ! Cheers

I added my main questions as comments in the code ;)